# Is there a minimum length for a 10GBase-DAC cable?

Tags: networking

I'm working on a network design in space constrained cabinets and trying to minimize the amount of cable coiled in the racks. The network is using HP A5820 switches and running 10Gigabit Ethernet to the servers in the rack. Is there a minimum cable length that I can use? The minimum length that HP sells is .65 meters but we'd like to have another vendor build us shorter cables if the Ethernet spec supports this. Does anyone know the spec that governs SFP+ to SFP+ Direct Attached Cables (DAC) for 10G? Does anyone have experience with cables shorter than 1 m?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Direct Attached Copper Cable, HP itself does sell a 0.65m cable (SKU JD095B). I've used cables of similar build for non-10GbE installations, and they're pretty short. They work, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about maximum length for cables, but I have not come across a minimum length, so normally there should no problem. 
Most of the time it is because signals go lower or you need CD on your cable. But non of this is going to happen on a  shorter cable.